# Querying for tasks in a private project using Asana API

Tags: api, asana

Do we have an API to query for tasks in a private project? Or are private projects/tasks invisible to all APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are visible to the API, if the API is operating on behalf of a user who can see them. It all depends on the user who authorized the API.